# split string with csv file golang

Tags: go

I'm trying to extract a date from an excel spreadsheet, I managed to give a log where it shows the entire date, I wanted to know how to extract only the month, for example, in this case it's "log.Println("DT REFER", emp. DT_REFER" the DT_REFER is where the date is in the spreadsheet, how can I get only the month out of it? the format that came was this.
DT REFER 2011-03-31

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fmt.Sscanf` to extract the month out of the log string that you have. Given you have a fixed string structure that you can match against as follows:

```golang
// if emp.DT_REFER isn't string use Sprint to make it string
s := fmt.Sprint(emp.DT_REFER)
y, m, d := 0, 0, 0
fmt.Sscanf(s, "%d-%d-%d", &y, &m, &d)
fmt.Println(y, m, d)
```

Comment: the problem is that it is getting it from a csv file inside the DT_REFER, I wanted to know how to get only the month out of it

Comment: I have updated the answer to consider we need to take out month from `DT_REFER` itself.